# How can I create a php data array from a mysql database to be used as input in PHPReport Maker

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, excel, pdf

I'm trying to create a report that is exportable to both Excel & PDF in PHP using [PHPReport](https://github.com/vernes/PHPReport). I have tested the report plugin and I have been able to create a suitable template to fit the report I want. However, I'm having difficulties figuring out how to use result sets from a mysql query as the input parameter to generate the report.

The report plugin only gives an example of an input data using an array of array as seen below.

```
$products=array(
    array('transdate'=>'Example product','ref'=>2,'debit'=>4.5,'credit'=>9, 'bal'=>2, 'narrative'=>'Yes'),
    array('transdate'=>'Example product','ref'=>2,'debit'=>4.5,'credit'=>9, 'bal'=>2, 'narrative'=>'Yes'),
    array('transdate'=>'Example product','ref'=>2,'debit'=>4.5,'credit'=>9, 'bal'=>2, 'narrative'=>'Yes'),
    array('transdate'=>'Example product','ref'=>2,'debit'=>4.5,'credit'=>9, 'bal'=>1122, 'narrative'=>'Yes'),
    array('transdate'=>'Example product','ref'=>2,'debit'=>4.5,'credit'=>9, 'bal'=>6, 'narrative'=>'Yes'),
    array('transdate'=>'Example product','ref'=>2,'debit'=>4.5,'credit'=>9, 'bal'=>5, 'narrative'=>'Yes')
);
```

**How can I use a result set from a Mysql query as input data ?**

Below is a example of the report generating script

```
<?php

include '../PHPReport.php';

//which template to use
if(isset($_GET['template']))
    $template=$_GET['template'];
else
    $template='invoice.xls';

//set absolute path to directory with template files
$templateDir='C:\wamp\www\ph\PHPReport\examples\template\\';

//we get some products, e.g. from database
$products=array(
    array('description'=>'Example product','qty'=>2,'price'=>4.5,'total'=>9),
    array('description'=>'Another product','qty'=>1,'price'=>13.9,'total'=>13.9),
    array('description'=>'Super product!','qty'=>3,'price'=>1.5,'total'=>4.5),
    array('description'=>'Yet another great product','qty'=>2,'price'=>10.8,'total'=>21.6),
    array('description'=>'Awesome','qty'=>1,'price'=>19.9,'total'=>19.9)
);

//set config for report
$config=array(
        'template'=>$template,
        'templateDir'=>$templateDir
    );

$R=new PHPReport($config);
$R->load(array(
            array(
                'id'=>'inv',
                'data'=>array(
                                'date'=>date('Y-m-d'),
                                'number'=>312,
                                'customerid'=>12,
                                'orderid'=>517,
                                'company'=>'Example Inc.',
                                'address'=>'Some address',
                                'city'=>'Some City, 1122',
                                'phone'=>'+111222333'
                            ),
                'format'=>array(
                        'date'=>array('datetime'=>'d/m/Y')
                    )
                ),
            array(
                'id'=>'prod',
                'repeat'=>true,
                'data'=>$products,
                'minRows'=>2,
                'format'=>array(
                        'price'=>array('number'=>array('prefix'=>'$','decimals'=>2)),
                        'total'=>array('number'=>array('prefix'=>'$','decimals'=>2))
                    )
                ),
            array(
                'id'=>'total',
                'data'=>array('price'=>68.9),
                'format'=>array(
                        'price'=>array('number'=>array('prefix'=>'$','decimals'=>2))
                    )
                )
            )
        );

echo $R->render('excel');
exit();
```